# Possible to constrain form data powershell?

Tags: winforms, powershell, ps2exe-gui

I created a Windows form in Powershell which I am then using PS2EXE-GUI to make an executable...I am struggling with this part, as it relies a LOT on user input to be correct:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "'Enter ID number for the Machine"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
```

And I would like to constrain what data can be input (must be 8 character length, start with specific characters, etc.).  Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `$textBox.MaxLength` to limit a text box to a certain number of characters. You can also use the events tied to the text box such as `KeyUp` to create logic to check for the start of entries and what is contained and inform the user at that point what is wrong with their entry.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler for the `TextChanged` event on the TextBox and evaluate the input whenever it changes:

```
$textBox.add_TextChanged({
    param($sender)

    if($sender.Text -match '^\d{6}\D{2}$'){
        # Input looks good, allow submission
        $submitButton.Enabled = $true
    }
    else {
        $submitButton.Enabled = $false
    }
})
```

In the above, we test that the input string consists of 6 digits and then 2 non-digits, but you can of course do any kind of testing you want in the event handler block